# How to click on IIS credential pop up message

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using latest version of WebDriver, I'm writing my code in C# and using console application project,

Do you familiar with a development package that has capabilities to use keyboard and mouse or send keys to the pop up message that is not part of DOM?

Switch to a frame or Alert using Selenium package is not a solution for that case, so I found InputSimulator package that know how to deal with it, but the problem is when you run the test on remote machine then there is a limitation in that package (some special characters are not pressed while using RDC),

Comment: *Selenium automates browsers*. Possible solution is [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/)

Comment: Thanks I will try this...read about it